# Binding dropdownlist asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, binding

I've populated a dropdownlist with data from my database. However, I'm unsure if my method is effective or not. What can I do to improve this or is the method I used secure/sufficient?

I have added the controller, the viewModel and the View below. All advice is greatly appreciated!

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SchedulerIndex()
    {
        Entities entities = new Entities();

        var getJobList = entities.Jobs.ToList();
        SelectList list = new SelectList(getJobList, "JobId", "JobName");
        ViewBag.jobListName = list;


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ScheduleInfo(Values model, int JobList1, string Second, string Minute, string Hour, object DayOfMonth, object Month, object DaysOfWeek, int repeatTime)
    {
        model.Job = JobList1;
```

View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ScheduleInfo", "Scheduler", FormMethod.Post))
{
    Html.EnableClientValidation();
<center>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <div class="form-group">
            <h4>Select a job from the list</h4>
            @Html.DropDownList("JobList1", ViewBag.jobListName as SelectList)
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class Values
{

    public List<object> DayOfMonth { get; set; }
    public List<object> Month { get; set; }
    public List<object> DaysOfWeek { get; set; }



    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a number between 0-59!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(,{0,1}(\b\d\b|[0-5][0-9]|\*+)(-\b\d\b|-[0-5][0-9]){0,1})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a number between 0-59!")]
    public object Second { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a number between 0-59!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(,{0,1}(\b\d\b|[0-5][0-9]|\*+)(-\b\d\b|-[0-5][0-9]){0,1})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a number between 0-59!")]
    public object Minute { get; set; }


    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter a number between 0-23!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(,{0,1}(\b\d\b|[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]|\*+)(-\b\d\b|-[0-1][0-9]|-[2][0-4]){0,1})$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a number between 0-23!")]
    public object Hour { get; set; }


    //public List<SelectListItem> Jobs { get; set; }
    public int Job { get; set; }

    public List<Values> DofMInfo { get; set; }
    public string DofMNo { get; set; }
    public int DofMID { get; set; }

    public List<Values> MonthInfo { get; set; }
    public int monthID { get; set; }
    public string monthName { get; set; }


    public List<Values> DayInfo { get; set; }
    public int dayID { get; set; }
    public string dayName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Enter the number of repeat times. 0 = execute once!")]
    public int repeatTime { get; set; }

    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: SO if for resolving issues with code that does not work. This should be posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing right now also okay but not recommended since you are using viewbag to keep the values and pass the values so instead of that you needs to create strongly typed models like below.

Create a new SelectListItem in model like below,

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> getJobList { get; set; }
```

And in controller

Assign the list values to the getJoblist selectedlistitem instead of viewbag.

Then in view bind the model data with the dropdown.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.jobList1, Model.getJobList)
```